# How do I incorporate new local changes into an existing Bitbucket repository?

Tags: git, bitbucket

I have a Bitbucket repository where I keep my projects. I committed all the projects at once using the following commands:

```
git init
git remote add origin (paste link from step 2)
git add .
git commit –a –m “First commit”
git push origin master
```

Now suppose that I want to add a new project to the repository. After I copy the project in the folder, which commands should I use to include this new project?

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend keeping different repos for each project, but to each their own... If you're ready to push your new project, do:

```
$ git add -A && git commit -m "Your Message"
$ git push origin master
```